# 10 of Av for Sefardim

Tags: halacha, minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tisha-bav, nine-days

I was told that Ashkenazim keep the 9 days until the midday of the 10th of av (no haircuts, showers, wine, meat...)

What do Sefardim do regarding this?
When is the first time that a Sefardi Jew can shave after the 9 days?

Comment: Sephardim keep the restrictions until sunset on 10 Av. Currently looking for a source to back up my claim.

Comment: @ezra it seems that it is only Regarding meat and wine https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.558

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shulhan Arukh (OH [551:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.551:4)) writes that one may cut hair and launder immediately following the fast, but it is a good custom to avoid meat and wine on the 10th ([558:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.558)).

R. Yitshak Yosef writes in Yalkut Yosef (OH: Od M'minhagei Yom Tish'a B'av [4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.553.4)-[5](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.553.5)) that it is a proper custom to refrain from meat and wine the night of the 10th of Av (i.e. the night immediately following the fast). However, that is only regarding meat and wine, but regarding bathing and cutting hair, unlike Ashkenazim, we are not accustomed to be stringent.

This is stated by other Sephardi authorities after the Shulhan Arukh including the [Shiurei K'nesset HaG'dolah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Benveniste) (OH 558:4) cited in Shu"t Yehave Da'at 5:41) by R. Ovadya Yosef who concurs.

Comment: Dead link.......